# New Line Character in PHP script on Remote Server not working

Tags: php, newline, echo

I am having trouble with "\n" character not working. I realized that it wasn't work while testing output of variables using a simple echo statement. I have tried approaching the new line character a few different ways to see if it was just me, but nothing I have tried is working. Here is an example of some attempts I have made:

```
<?php

    // Establish Connection to Taskaro DB
    require "../_connections/connection_taskDB.php";

    // Start Session
    session_start();

    // Create Session Variables
    $_SESSION['userID'];
    $_SESSION['companyID'];
    $_SESSION['usernameDB'];

    // Convert Session Variables to page variables
    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $currentUser = $_SESSION['usernameDB'];
    $editType = $_REQUEST['editType'];
    $projectID = $_REQUEST['projectID'];

    // Testing if new line character is working
    echo "hello, Mr. New Line!\n\r";
    echo "This line should be below 'hello, Mr. New Line!'";

    // Testing variable and session connection
    echo "SESSION VARIABLES:"."\\n\n"."userID = {$userID}";
    echo "userID = {$userID}"."/n";
    echo "currentUser = {$currentUser}"."\r";
    echo "companyID = {$companyID}\n\r";
    echo "\nPOST VARIABLES:\n";
    echo "editType = {$editType}\n";
    echo "projectID = {$projectID}\n";


?>
```

I read up on some other overflow questions that had similar problems and none of them fixed my problem. The project is on a remote server (GoDaddy) in which php has been installed. The document has the correct file extension (.php). I am coding in dreamweaver and uploading my script for testing. From the code you can see I've tried "\n","\n\r","\r". I've also tested in both Firefox and Google Chrome.

I also tried to concatenate the "\n" character, and took a shot in the dark and even tried using the forward slash rather than the backslash (I knew it wouldn't work, but I'm getting pretty frustrated at this point). I bet it's something simple but I don't see what else is could be. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you looking at this in a browser? You'll need to use `<br />` for a new line there.

Comment: I am looking at it in a browser. I thought that the new line character also works when using echo

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492945/php-syntax-for-new-line-is-not-working

Answer (score 4):

If you view the source of the page, you will see all of those values output on separate lines.

If you are viewing the file in the browser, you need to use line breaks (`<br />`) if you want your text to show up on different lines.  HTML ignores newlines in regards to presentation.

```
echo "hello, Mr. New Line!\n";
echo "This line should be below 'hello, Mr. New Line!'";
```

When viewing source, the above two text strings will be on separate lines.  When viewed in the browser they will appear to be on the same line.

```
echo "hello, Mr. New Line!\n<br />";
echo "This line should be below 'hello, Mr. New Line!'";
```

When viewing source, the above two text strings will be on separate lines because of the `\n`.  When viewed in the browser they will also be on separate lines because of the HTML break `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP_EOL constant instead of `\n` and call it a day.

Also, it's `\r\n`, not the other way around.

If you are expecting the browser to render new line characters as new lines in HTML, that won't happen. You need to use the `<br>` tag.